# Getting acces to Central Administration

Tags: 2010, permissions, central-administration

I work in a company with SharePoint. My permission level is: "Full control". However there are few things I need to change but I do not have an acces. For example: Editing Master Page in SharePoint Designer.

-How can I get acces to SharePoint central administration (do I have to be a site admin?)

-How to check who is site admin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Query 1: How can I get acces to SharePoint central administration (do I have to be a site admin?)*

Two sets of users are allowed to perform administrative functions for Microsoft.

**1. Members of the administrators group for the local server computer.**

This can be done from "Active directory users and computers" program. Open "Active directory users and computers" on server--> Click on Built-in groups --> Find Administrators group --> Add member.

Members of the Administrators group on the local server computer have full control of all applications running on that server, including Internet Information Services (IIS), Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft ASP.NET, and . These administrators can perform any task on that server, including all administration tasks for , such as controlling administrative functions, configuring settings at the server or virtual server level, and creating or changing sites and lists.

**2. Members of the SharePoint administration group.**

This can be done from SharePoint central administration itself. & can only be done by admin of central admin. Go to SharePoint central administration site -->  Click on Security--->Manage the farm administrators group---> Add user

Members of the SharePoint administration group can perform SharePoint Central Administration tasks, but do not have access to the file system of the server or the IIS metabase, so they cannot perform actions on other applications running on the server, such as IIS, Microsoft SQL Server, ASP.NET.

So, Member of any above group can able to access SharePoint central administration.

---

*Query 2: How to check who is site admin?*

You can find it using following two ways

**1. Site Setting:**

Go to site setting ---> Users and Permissions ---> Site collection administrators (Site Collection Administrators are given full control over all sites in the site collection. )

**2. Central administration:**

Go to central administration --> Application Management --> Change Site Collection Administrators (change site collection from site collection drop down to check respective site collection admin)

---

Comment: About Query 2: What if I don't have an access to central administration and 'Site collection administrators' option is not visible for me? Is there another possibility to check who is site admin?

Comment: @ Daniel..Option one is still there

Comment: You can also use code to check site admin. CSOM/SSOM

Comment: And how I can use this CSOM/SSOM ? In which program or application should I write a code?

Comment: In visual studio you can write the code. you can use console application. just google about it, you will get idea. Otherwise post new question about how to get site admin programmatically. you will get answers.

Answer (score 1):

To access central administration:
if we are talking about Sharepoint on premise, you can check the user right into IIS sharepoint application pool ( and use that user to log on into central admin)

About user permission to edit Master pages and such:
first check if the master is not  checked out by someone else  (like sys administrator ) 
if this is not the case you should look better **where** you have the "full control" and inheritance.

hope this will help!